# Line breaks are being lost when sending text to the Database

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

For some reason the line breakes from ASP.NET textboxes are not being stored in my database.

I am using Server.HtmlEncode(txtAbout.Text) to take the text from the textbox.
This part works and text is taken out with line breaks.

But when I trace the text, the line breaks are lost after this line:

```
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "About", DbType.String, about);
db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
```

In the stored procedure the varable @about is ntext.
In the table the column about is ntext

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Can you do txtAbout.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"<br />") ?

Comment: I cant do that because if the about text is edited later then I dont want the user to see mark up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you trace what the value of "about" is before sending it off to the stored procedure?

I suspect what is happening is when you are outputting the stored result, you are assigning it to a label. Rather output it to a literal:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" id="litAbout" />
```

Then once you have done that, then do the "placement". For example:

```
litAbout.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(aboutText).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
```

Also, that is where you want to encode the output. You almost always only do the final transformations prior to outputting the result; the thinking is that you don't want to lose that raw input.

Comment: Solution worked perfectly. The thing that got me was that I cant see any line breaks in the table but like you said it still stored them.

Answer (score 1):

Outputting to a label isn't the problem.  The problem is outputting it to a label without doing the replace Justin mentioned.

I just tested this in VS2010 (.NET 3.5) and it worked.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAbout" />

lblAbout.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(aboutText).Replace(Environment.Newline, "<br />");
```

This solution will work the same as the literal.