# How to preserve textarea content formatting while saving it to database and displaying it in view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on asp.net mvc. I am trying to save form-data to the database. I have the form with one textarea where user can type the text or he can paste the text from somewhere. Here i  need to save the text of textarea into database. and then i need to show the textarea content what he saved,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("myaction", "mycontrolller", FormMethod.Post, 
                                              new { id = "addform" }))
{
     <textarea id="note" name="note"></textarea>
     <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Now  i am able to get the data that user entered into my post action from view, But the text doesn't contain any line breaks or carriage returns though he pasted multiple paragraph text. While i am in debugging and watch the text content in Text Visualizer, it shows me with exact format. But when i save it into the database. It save it as single line of text and so shows me as a single line of text, when i displayed.

I have tried the following code,

```
obj.Notes = obj.Notes
               .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")
               .Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
```

But it doesn't resolve my problem. It still displays single line of continuous text though it have multi-paragraph text.

Comment: Find the C# equivalent for http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php or add <pre></pre> tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078882/line-breaks-are-being-lost-when-sending-text-to-the-database

Answer (score 1):

Yes I've got solution to my answer after a small trial, just displayed the content in `<pre>` tag instead of `<p>`

Replaced from:

```
    <p>Data from Database</p>
```

to

```
    <pre>Data from Database</pre>
```